# Can't post object from form by Ajax SpringMVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How to post object to controller from form by jquery ajax? 
I have object User:

```
private String name;
private int age;

public User(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

I have controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    System.out.println(user.getName());
}
```

I generate form by jquery:

```
function createForm() {
    $("body").append($('<form id="form1" method="POST"></form>'));
    $("form").append('<input type="text" id="name">');
    $("form").append('<input type="text" id="age">');
    $("form").append('<input type="button" onclick="formSubmit();" value="Ok">');}
```

And i try get data by ajax to my controller:

```
function formSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : 'rest/user',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : $('#form1').serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
            doAjax();
        }
    });
}
```

Method doAjax just generate results of db.

But it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you have set `dataType` to `json`,but the `data` is pure string due to you using `$('#form1').serialize()`.

In order to get data,you need to remove `dataType` in your `ajax` method.

```
function formSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : 'rest/user',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        //dataType : 'json',
        data : $('#form1').serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
            doAjax();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I got this exception:
WARNING: Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public void iful.edu.RestMVC.controller.SpringRestController.createUser(iful.edu.RestMVC.model.User)

Comment: @КолянДзьоба add your spring controller code in your question

Comment: He is. Check the top of the question, after "I have controller:"

Comment: @КолянДзьоба remove `@RequestBody` in your controller and try again

Comment: Method returns null. I think data from form doesn't post to controller

Comment: check your url in ajax